# Show $z := H - h$ lies in the center of $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{s}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am current reading the paper: Classification of Good Gradings of Simple Lie Algebras, here's [a link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285850714_Classification_of_good_gradings_of_simple_Lie_algebras)!

**Lemma 1.1:**
Let $e \in \mathfrak{g}_2$, $e \neq 0$.

Then there exists $h \in \mathfrak{g}_0$ and $f \in g_{-1}$
such that $\{e, h, f\}$ form an $sl_2$-triple,

i.e., $[h, e] = 2e, [e, f] = h, [h, f] =-2f.$

**Theorem 1.1:**
Let $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathfrak{g}_j$ be a good $\mathbb{Z}$-grading and $e \in \mathfrak{g}_2$ a good element.

Let $H \in \mathfrak{g}$ be the element defining the $\mathbb{Z}$-grading 
(i.e., $\mathfrak{g}_j = \{a \in \mathfrak{g} \ | \ [H, a] =
ja\}$), and let $\mathfrak{s}= \{e, h, f\}$ be an $sl_2$-triple given by above Lemma.

Then $z := H - h$ lies in the center of $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{s}$.

I want to ask the following

1. Why such $H$ exists? My idea is left multiplication by $j$ is a derivation, then $[H,a]=ja$ since any derivation is inner, but how to show $H$ is independent of $j$?
2. In the proof of the theorem on P.3, why $\mathfrak{g}^s$ is reductive implies $[H, \mathfrak{g}^s] = 0$?
   Is it because of $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{s}\subseteq\mathfrak{g}_0$?

Thank you for helping!